# ASP.NET How to define what columns to display in Dynamic GridView User Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I have a user control that contains a GridView. I create an instance of the user control in the code behind of the page I want to display it in. Because the datasource can be different for different instances of the user control, how can I define which columns get displayed when setting up the GridView user control? (I don't want to display all the columns in the datasource)

I have the following code:

```
gridView.DataSource = Query.ToArray();
            placeHolder1.Controls.Add(gridView);
```

And the following code in the user control code behind:

```
this.GridView1.DataSource = DataSource;
            GridView1.DataBind();
```

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: do you know the name of columns which you don't want to display?

Comment: Yes, but how can I specify these when setting up the user control in code?

Comment: After giving datasource to gridview use gridview.columns[].visible = false. Mention name or index of column in sqaure brackets.

Comment: I don't seem to be able to use GridView.Columns

Comment: You can't find Columns in gridview properties in code file?

Comment: Maybe it's because it's a user control?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3590/discussion-between-emaad-ali-and-aspdotnetuser)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this code,

```
  GridView.Columns[0].Visible = false;
```

use this line after assigning datasource to gridview, place column index or name in square brackets.

Or check this code too.

Before your DataBind(). write this:

`GridView.DataBound += new EventHandler(GridView_DataBound);`

create this method in your code GridView_DataBound and write in that method, the code to hide the columns.

Hope my answer helps you.

Comment: It won't let me put GridView1.Columns it says it's can't find columns, but I can use the GridView1.DataSource

Comment: Sorry my mistake make it Gridview.columns[0].visible = false.

Answer (score -1):

You can pass parameters to the usercontrol from the page u use it in. Use a switch/case for all the "columncollections" you have then pass the type from the page and change the columns to fit the page.